# How do I abort print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

Is there a way to abort the print event after a user has pressed the web browsers print button?

This works for print buttons within the HTML (jQuery):

```
print_btn.click(function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to print? Consider the environment")) {
        window.print();
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do the same with the web browsers print button? For IE there seemes to be a onbeforeprint event, but from there I can't find a way to abort the printing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible in general, and honestly I'm quite glad that's the case.

You could, however, do something dirty like make a style sheet that uses media selectors to make everything `display: none;` when printing, or something similar. I haven't ever tried this but it seems totally within spec (if completely pretentious).

Comment: wouldn't help for the page title, page numbering etc. that browsers are inserting.

Comment: Sure, but if his goal is really to "consider the environment", at least he'd save a marginal amount of ink. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to `return false;` in IE's onbeforeprint event?

I doubt it's possible in any other browsers but IE. Having said that, it wouldn't surprise me if it worked in IE using the onbeforeprint event. Shocking, I know.

Comment: Well, can't be done then. Don't forget that all the JavaScript code runs inside its own sandbox, it would be a security risk if you had any control (even cancelling) over built-in functions like Print, File Save etc. of the hosting browser.